# In Sphinx Search, how do I add "hashtag" to the charset_table?

Tags: search, unicode, utf-8, lucene, sphinx

I would like people to be able to search `#photography` as well as `photography`.  Those should be treated as two different words in Sphinx.  By default, `#photography` maps to `photography`, and I can't search for hashtags.

I read on [this page](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=4564) that you can add the hash tag to the charset_table to accomplish this. I am completely clueless on how to do that. I don't know unicode, and I don't know what my charset_table should be.

Can someone tell me what my charset_table should be? Thanks.

```
# charset_table     = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F
```

**Note: I plan on using real-time index. (not sure if this makes a difference)**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's `U+0023` according to the Unicode table. So the final config should be like

```
charset_table     = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+23, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F
```

Don't forget about `charset_type` variable. AFAIK, this example `charset_table` is for `utf-8`. Besides this, you should delete `U+23` from `blend_chars` variable to allow Sphinx to index it as a legit character.

Comment: Thanks Paul. What would the entire string look like? Do I just add that to the end, with a comma before it?  Not sure what the final result will be...

Comment: Updated and provided some more info.

Comment: In addition to the current requirement, is there any way to make it so that when users search "photography", it also returns results from "#photography"? But not the other way around...

Comment: `expand_keywords` should resolve this issue, though `infix search` ought to be used instead of `prefix search`. I don't know if it works with special characters, such as hash sign.

Answer (score 0):

> > > I would like people to be able to search #photography as well as photography. Those should be treated as two different words in Sphinx. By default, #photography maps to photography, and I can't search for hashtags.

good day.

i think it wiil some workaround for you problem, but:

it's bad way to call search function directly from user query.

before call search function in sphinx engine, you need to make some kind of processing on user string.
for example you may check user string for some kind of special characters and delete special characters from query. aftet you may call search function with proceeded query.

good luck.